# Value of $\log(x)-\log(-x) $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

According to wolframalpha $\log(a)-\log(-a) = i\pi$ for $a<0$ and $-i\pi$ for $a>0$

This is the integral $\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{x}dx$

I guess we have to be smart with complex integration then...?

Still, i can not fully fanthom how a real integral can have complex output though...

Has anyone enlighting ideas?

Comment: Does that integral exist?

Comment: It isn't defined for $0 ∈ [-a,a]$, you have to take a path through the plane to achieve a well-defined integral. Then it becomes plausible that it has a complex value.

Comment: But he says "real integral," which indicates he thinks it is a non-complex integral, @K.Stm.

Comment: Are you asked to find the Cauchy principal value of the integral?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It’s still true that you have to take a path through the complex plane to (well)-define this integral, which means it needs to become a complex integral to be well-defined. That’s my point.

Comment: Normally, when sticking to the reals, one uses the antiderivative $$\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln|x| + C$$ If one considers this a function of all nonzero reals (rather than sticking to positive numbers or to negative numbers), one must remember that $C$ isn't required to be constant, but merely *locally constant*. That is, $C$ is any function
$$ x \mapsto \begin{cases} C_+ & x > 0 \\ C_- & x < 0 \end{cases} $$
where $C_+$ and $C_-$ *are* constants.

Comment: Ah thank you. Well no. The actual reason Im asking this is because i want to show that $\phi \mapsto \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}dx$ is a distribution. So for $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. But that's another subject ...;p Therefore i need to have some bound on the integral.

Comment: Ah thank you, I think that last comment is just what i need. The fact that its locally constant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integral clearly does not exist, there is no problem. 
Integrals of real functions will continue to give real values.

To see that the integral does not exist even with generalized integral, write:
$$\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{x} dx =\int_{-a}^{-\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} dx + \int_{\delta}^a \frac{1}{x} dx = \log(\epsilon/a) - \log(\delta/a)$$
Since this can get arbitrary values for any choice of $\epsilon(\delta)$, the generalized integral isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

However the @rlgoronma's answer light the way, but note that the function $f(x)=1/x$ has a discontinuity point at the origin and I don't think that improper integrals can help you.

Comment: This function IS continuous everywhere it is defined. Consequently, it has no discontinuity points.

Comment: @user60253: Clearly I mean on $[-a,a]$, it has such that point.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you are envisaging $\log(-x)$ for some $x>0$ you cannot make sense of it unless you are transcending into the complex domain. There the function $\log$ takes values not in ${\mathbb C}$, but in ${\mathbb C}/(2\pi i{\mathbb Z})$. This means that $\log z$ is defined only "up to an additive multiple of $2\pi i\>$"; it is given by
$$\log z=\log|z| + i\arg (z)\qquad(z\ne0)\ ,$$
where $\arg (z)$ is the "polar angle" of $z$ up to a multiple of $2\pi$. As
$|-z|=|z|$ and $\arg(-z)=\arg (z)+[\pi]$ for all $z\ne0$ we find that
$$\log(z)-\log(-z)= i[\pi]=\{\pi i +2k\pi\>i\ |\ k\in{\mathbb Z}\}\qquad(z\ne0)\ ,$$
and there is no way out of this indeterminacy.

To make things more convenient one introduces the *principal value* of $\log$, called ${\rm Log}$. This function is defined in ${\mathbb C}$ minus the negative real axis und is equal to the representant of $\log$ having imaginary part in $\ ]{-\pi},\pi[\ $. Unfortunately we cannot make use of this escape when $z=x>0$, because $-z$ then lies on the negative real axis.